# Number theory AMC practice problem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

> For two positive integers $m$ and $n$, suppose $\gcd(m,n)\cdot \textrm{lcm}(m,n)=2016$.
>   What is the minimum possible value of $m+n$?

I managed to use the property here that $\gcd(m,n)\cdot \textrm{lcm}(m,n)$ implies thtat $m \cdot n = 2016$. After that  I prime factorized $2016 = 2^5 \cdot 3^2\cdot 7.$ However here I got a bit stuck. The proposed solution for this was very vague and relied on "guess and check" I'm not sure how that would actually work here since there seems to be $35$ possible factors for $2016$ in pairs of two and "guessing and checking" would not be very efficient. How could I avoid this?

Comment: Since $(m+n)^2=(m-n)^2+4mn$, you just have to find the pair $(m,n)$ s.t. $|m-n|$ is smallest.  In other words, what is the smallest integer $k$ s.t. $4mn+k^2$ is a perfect square?

Comment: In view of @WETutorialSchool 's  comment the problem reduces to finding the divisor of 2016 which is closest to $\sqrt{2016}$.

Comment: Another way of looking the same is to use AM-GM inequality $\frac{m+n}{2} \geq \sqrt{mn}$. Equality (hence the min of the sum) occurs when $m =n$. So as @Vahe pointed out, you should be looking for integers closes to $\sqrt{2016}$.

Answer (score 1):

there are two really  basic factoring methods. The one we call Fermat's method is just to take the squares slightly larger than the target, see if the difference is a square.  So, $45^2 = 2025$ and $2025 - 2016 = 9.$

So $2025 - 9 = 2016$ and $(45+3)(45-3) = 2016,$ and $48+42 = 90$

Fermat's is intended for odd numbers, works for multiples of 4. If you have twice an odd number, first you must divide out the 2 factor, since the difference of two squares is never $2 \pmod 4$